# Cloned site with tricky HTTP_HOST

Tags: apache, web-hosting

Another site has cloned mine.  The site in question is netdna-cdn.com, and if you do a search on Google  ("site:netdna-cdn.com") you will see it has cloned 100's if not 1000's of sites.

So in times past the way I have dealt with this is to submit a DMCA complaint with Google, and put the following in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which redirects all domains not of mine, back to mine.  However, after some tests I think HTTP_HOST actually contains my domain, but it definitely is coming from netcdn-dna.com.

The best I could do was grab HTTP_REFERER (which contained netdna-cdn.com) and redirect all images requests to a warning image that says the person is on the wrong site.

One more thing, when I run

```
curl -v http://example.site.netdna-cdn.com
```

The host header shows up as the correct one, but the apache directive above doesn't seem to think anything is wrong with the host.

Is there another way through apache or PHP to get the real host?  Is there any thing else I should be doing to mitigate damages that could potentially be caused by this cloned site?

Comment: You did not not subscribe to any of these services offering free SSL and faster content delivery, aka CDN services, do you?

Comment: They are a low end CDN provider - they offer a service where static content is cloned to regional end points, which is offered bundled through some web hosting packages. The idea is that links on pages are made to the CDN version of static assets, allowing them to load faster. Most of the sites in Google appear to be intentionally using this function - they may even be paying for it.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf After some searching I am using cdn's to load some of my resources like maxcdn.boostrapcdn.com, oss.maxcdn.com, cdnjs.cloudflare.com...  But I am not paying for any of them, and only wanted access to some javascript and css like bootstrap and font-awesome, I didn't subscribe to any of them